# I am not getting why is the error coming up "illegal parenthesized expression"

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
import java.util.*;
public class scan2
{
void main ()
{ 
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("enter sides of cube ");
double s = sc.nextDouble();

System.out.println("enter sides of sphere ");
double r = sc.nextDouble();

System.out.println("enter sides of cuboid ");
double l = sc.nextDouble();
double b = sc.nextDouble();
double h = sc.nextDouble();


switch (option)
{
case '1':
double cube = s*s*s;
System.out.println("volume of cube " +cube);   
break;

case '2':
double sph = 4/3*22/7*r*r*r;
System.out.println("volume of sphere " +sph);
break;

case '3':
double cuboid = l*b*h;
System.out.println("enter sides of cuboid ");
break;
}
}
}
```

I am not getting why is the error coming up with "illegal parenthesized expression". It's coming on switch(option) line. And when option is removed inside brackets its showing an error as "illegal start of expression".

Comment: `option` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Unrelated, but please consider indenting your code--it makes things much easier to think about.

Comment: *Completely* unrelated, but spheres don't have sides.

Comment: Also, `4/3*22/7*r*r*r` doesn't give the result you intend. Have a read about integer division and operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't define `option`
For variable you should declare before use.
I advise you can use IDE like InteliJ IDEA to format your code and find error.